# Making private constructor and creating secondary constructor gives error in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Below code snippet gives error. Can someone guide why this is happening?

```
class Test() private constructor {
        
    constructor(name: String): this() {
        println("test called constructor $name")
    }
   
}

fun main() {
    Test("hk")
}
```

Removing private constructor , this is working.

I tried to resolve this on my side. but I got no success.

I am getting this error: `Expecting a top level declaration Expecting a top level declaration Function declaration must have a name Unresolved reference: constructor Unresolved reference: name Unexpected type specification Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) Unresolved reference: name`

Comment: I am getting this error: Expecting a top level declaration
Expecting a top level declaration
Function declaration must have a name
Unresolved reference: constructor
Unresolved reference: name
Unexpected type specification
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
Unresolved reference: name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Test private constructor() {

  constructor(name: String): this() {
    println("test called constructor $name")
  }

}

fun main() {
  Test("hk")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `()` after `Test` is the constructor - it's shorthand for `Test constructor()` - think of it like a special function called `constructor`.

So if you want to make that function private, you need to explicitly use the `constructor()` name with the parentheses, and then you can add `private` before it.

```
class Test private constructor()
```

More info here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test{

  private  constructor(){}

  constructor(name: String): this() {
     println("test called constructor $name")
  }
}
```